# Which OpenJDK Build does Ubuntu use?

Tags: compiling, openjdk, jdk, default

Which OpenJDK 11 Build does Ubuntu install by default? My understanding is that beginning by OpenJDK 11, Oracle doesn't support OpenJDK long term. That is why that other builds like AdoptOpenJDK gained in popularity.

So which build of OpenJDK is installed in Ubuntu by default?

Thanks

Comment: https://packages.ubuntu.com/hirsute/openjdk-11-jdk  (you haven't provided release details, so adjust for your release as I used mine .. it's not hard following links from the package itself)

Comment: I think you dont understand my question

Comment: The link I provided shows details of the package, and provides a link to upstream or the project where the source code comes from (for my release as you didn't provide a specific release). Packages are built from source code, I've provided that Ubuntu source code for the actual package & the upstream project where it comes from (the latest JDK15 is binary only; the upstream (Oracle) page mentions that, but JDK11 is open source as it states on Oracle's web site in the link provided in first comment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most distro vendors will make their own build from source for open source software. In this case Ubuntu has a branch of OpenJDK sources which I are kept up to date with CVE and other bug fixes. You can look at the commit history [here](https://git.launchpad.net/%7Eopenjdk/ubuntu/+source/openjdk/+git/openjdk/log/?h=openjdk-11).

They might mix and match whatever patches are neccesary on their branch.

So to answer your question it appears that ubuntu provides its own build of OpenJDK which likely pulls patches for bugs and security vulnerabilities from upstream as may be necessary.